# Can't use my backup of MySQL data with a new installation?

Tags: mysql, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server

When I copy my MySQL `data` backup into the `datadir` folder and start the service with `net start mysql`, it throws an error 1067.

The new data, created when the server was installed works fine.

Is there any way to import my data from the backup?

## Solution:

I opened `services.msc` and checked what command-line arguments are called when the service starts. After that I opened the same in `cmd` plus the additional `--console` parameter for the output.

Turns out the problem was caused by mismatched log sizes, so I looked that up on SO and solved the issue as follows:

1. Redirected the `datadir` parameter to the working `data`;
2. Started MySQL;
3. `SET GLOBAL innodb_fast_shutdown=0;`
4. Stopped MySQL;
5. Changed `datadir` to my backup;
6. Removed the `_ib_logfile*` files from the new `datadir`;
7. Started MySQL;

Works like a charm!

Comment: Can you post us the whole error ? Also provide the steps which you did. We need more relevant information

Comment: How do I get more info on the error? That's all the CMD shows when I try to start the `mysql` service. As to the steps I'm taking, I'm stopping the server, copying my backup into the `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\data` and *trying* to start the server again.

Comment: @Noob tried updating MySQL server to 5.7. Now it say that the service couldn't be started but instead of the old error code I'm getting `The service did not report an error.`